# How do GADT data constructor arguments work in Idris?

Tags: implicit, idris, gadt

Here is a GADT with three data constructors defining a view for lists:

```
data SplitList : List a -> Type where
  SplitNil : SplitList []
  SplitOne : SplitList [x]
  SplitPair : (lefts : List a) -> (rights : List a) ->
              SplitList (lefts ++ rights)
```

I don't understand `SplitOne`: where does the `[x]` come from? In `SplitNil`, it seems to just be a constant value (`Nil`) which is fed to `SplitList`, but in `SplitOne` is the `x` an implicit argument somehow?

Comment: maybe a "show implicits" command which I potentially forgot about would help me here, does it exist? `:doc` doesn't appear to show them by itself

Comment: I've found `:set showimplicits` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768877/idris-map-function-on-custom-dependent-data-type-fails.

Comment: Yes, it's a short form of `{x : a} -> SplitList [x]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert, but since nobody else is answering: Yes, and so is the `a` in the first line: [`List a -> Type` is short for `{a : Type} -> List a -> Type`](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#implicit-arguments).

By type inference, `x` must have type `a`, so `[x] : List a` and `SplitList [x] : Type`. 
What I am not sure about is whether

1. this `a` is another implicit argument, so that the full type signature is `SplitOne : {a : Type} -> {x : a} -> SplitList [x]` (and if so, is its name really `a`?), or
2. it's somehow bound by the `a` from the first line.

But the first makes more sense to me.

Comment: It's a mix of 1 and 2 :) The full signature is `SplitOne : {b : Type} -> {x : b} -> SplitList {a=b} [x]`

Comment: I'd put that as "1, but I missed an implicit argument to `SplitList` and the name is not `a`" :)